# Hibernate Criteria for order by and group by

Tags: java, hibernate

I have entity:

```
class Person{
    Integer id;
    String name;
}
```

And entity

```
class History{
    Person person;
    Date date;
}
```

I want to select records, where `name` equals `Ann` and `date` is later for `Ann`. For example:

```
Person:
1 Ann
2 Mary
3 Ann

History
1 2015-02-02
2 2015-02-03
1 2015-02-07
3 2015-03-14
```

And result :

```
History
1 2015-02-07
3 2015-03-14
```

How to create a criteria with subselect?

Comment: You can use `DetachedCriteria`. Refer - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/apb.html#querycriteria-detachedqueries

Comment: why not use a join instead?